# jQuery Ajax Error - Stack Trace

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

How can I get stack trace from [jQuery Ajax Error](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/).

Answer (score 3):

Some may want to know how to evaluate the stack of the source ajax call invoking the success/error, since that happens in a new thread. The following may be useful for some arriving at this old question:

```
var callingState = new Error(); // capture state/stack when ajax is called
jQuery.ajax({// just showing error property
    error: function() {
        // employ "closure" to access values from the ajax context
        // access stack showing context when ajax was called
        alert('Caller stack: ' + callingState.stack);
        // access stack during "error" callback
        alert('Current stack: ' + (new Error()).stack);
    }
});
```

Read more about "closure" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome I like using the debugger keyword: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#printing-stack-traces
However, depending on the nature of the problem, you may need to do pass in async: false or use some other strategy to get the stack trace you may need (instead of the stack trace of the error callback, which can often be less interesting to your problem).

Comment: This looks promising https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js  I will test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

On firefox, this is pretty simiple. You put a breakpoint on the inside of the handler, fire the ajax and your browser will pause execution. On the debugger tab of your Development Tools just click on the Call Stack subsection on the right top side of the left pane.

[image: Firefox Debugger Call Stack]

There's also `console.trace()` if you want to print the stack trace.

Comment: Hi @MinusFour, this is correct, but the thing is I don't want to do this manually, I want to write a script from where I want to monitor exeptions, and for that I need stack trace, and this console.trace() is not cross-browser solution.

Answer (score -3):

You can add this in your ajax command.

```
jQuery.ajax({// just showing error property
           error: function(jqXHR,error, errorThrown) {  
               if(jqXHR.status&&jqXHR.status==400){
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText); 
               }else{
                   alert("Something went wrong");
               }
          }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Hermes, this does not apply to my question. My question is not how to get error message in specific ajax call, my question is how to get full stack trace in global jQuery ajax error callback.